# How to fix error "vector iterators in range are from different containers" in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't know where is the problem. The program crashes in this function. Can you help me?

I use these 2 functions for benchmarking (comparing containers speed with different techniques of using it). I use vector "studentai" with all students name and lastname in it. At vector "silpni" are students, which final score is >5. And, of course, "geri" with score <5. This function work well:

```
void atrinkimas_1(vector <duomenys>& studentai, vector <duomenys>& silpni, vector <duomenys>& geri)
{
    sort(studentai.begin(), studentai.end(), tikrinimas_gal);
    std::vector<duomenys>::iterator it = std::find_if(studentai.begin(), 
    studentai.end(), tikrinimas_5);
    std::copy(it, studentai.end(), std::back_inserter(geri));
    studentai.resize(studentai.size() - geri.size());
    std: copy(studentai.begin(), it, std::back_inserter(silpni));
    studentai.clear();
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
void atrinkimas_2(vector <duomenys>& studentai, vector<duomenys> &silpni)
{
    sort(studentai.begin(), studentai.end(), tikrinimas_gal);
    std::vector<duomenys>::iterator it = std::find_if(studentai.begin(), studentai.end(), tikrinimas_5);
    std::copy(it, studentai.end(), std::back_inserter(silpni));
    studentai.resize(studentai.size() - silpni.size());
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is this error from the compiler (if so, what line does it report)? Occurring at runtime? What compiler? I can't help but notice you're not checking the return from `find_if`, and I have no idea if `std::copy` is guaranteed to work when `first` is a past the end iterator (I suspect it works, but don't want to assume).

Comment: Yes. This is a runtime error. Debugging with the Clion.

Comment: The above code doesn't compile for reasons utterly unrelated to your error.  It is unclear if the code you have above would actually reproduce your error at runtime or not (ie, if there are more typos) -- or maybe it would compile (`std:` instead of `std::` could introduce a label, then `copy` is found via ADL?).  Types `duomenys` and function `tikrinimas_5` is missing.  [MCVE], and *ensure it actually reproduces the error*.

Comment: @GytautėBarzdžiūtė *At vector "silpni" are students, which final score is >5. And, of course, "geri" with score <5. This function work well:* -- Why didn't you simply use `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition` if this is your goal?  Your code seems to be doing something that looks like an STL algorithm call or two would work, with more efficiency and no bugs (or very few bugs).

Answer (score 2):

By resizing `studentai`, you’ve invalidated `it`. I would guess that the error is that `it` doesn’t point into `studentai` anymore.

Comment: This call to `studentai.resize` would only ever shrink (or maintain) the size of `studentai`. Shrinking a vector does not invalidate all iterators (because it does not reallocate). The code he shows would leave `it == student.end()` after the resize (assuming `silpni` started empty) and, in any case, the resize happens after the use of `it`. I don't know what the problem is with his code but I don't think this is it... perhaps memory corruption from elsewhere.

Comment: Practically you may be right, but I think technically invalidation acts as though you popped back and pop back invalidates iterators to the the popped item and to end, which is where `it` points so I think `it` May well be invalidated, technically, in which case we’d expect a runtime error if this runtime error checking is sufficiently pedantic.

Comment: It does invalidate it, since its not a part of the vector after the resize.

Comment: If `silpni` was passed in empty then `it == studentai.end()` after the resize. No, you can't dereference the end() iterator (...ever) but there is no dereference even attempted here.

A crash on the resize is possible if `silpni` isn't passed in empty. If `silpni.size() > studentai.size()`, where both `size()` and `resize(...)` work w/ unsigned types... out-of-memory error.